# Check for perfect square and replace with another value in R

Tags: r

I have attempted multiple different ways to check for perfect squares in an R object then replace with 0's. Below are the multiple single lines of codes I have tried; code must be a single line:

```
> y
 [1]  9 72 49 70 16  3  3  4 81  6 43  7 12  9  3

 is.integer(sqrt(y))
[1] FALSE

> ifelse(is.integer(sqrt(y)), 0, y)
[1] 9

> ifelse(sqrt(y)==is.integer(y), 0, y)
 [1]  9 72 49 70 16  3  3  4 81  6 43  7 12  9  3
```

Comment: `is.integer` returns a single TRUE/FALSE

Comment: not doing what i am expecting it to do here. it just returns a single boolean value. What element is this value for? @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a condition with `round` or `ceiling` or `as.integer` which convert to integer and only those that are exactly matching will return TRUE because of the precision involved

```
y[sqrt(y) == round(sqrt(y))] <- 0

y[sqrt(y) == as.integer(sqrt(y))] <- 0
```

#### data

```
y <- c(9, 72, 49, 70, 16, 3, 3, 4, 81, 6, 43, 7, 12, 9, 3)
```

Comment: That one does it. Thanks a lot! I have been at it for the past hour. Do you mind a little explanation @Akrun?

Comment: @YokoKoko i added some info

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the number by 1 and get the remainder using `%%` and compare the value with 0.

```
sqrt(y)
#[1] 3.00 8.49 7.00 8.37 4.00 1.73 1.73 2.00 9.00 2.45 6.56 2.65 3.46 3.00 1.73

sqrt(y) %% 1 == 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now turn these values to 0 by :

```
y[sqrt(y) %% 1 == 0] <- 0
#[1]  0 72  0 70  0  3  3  0  0  6 43  7 12  0  3
```

Or another way :

```
y * +(sqrt(y) %% 1 != 0)
#[1]  0 72  0 70  0  3  3  0  0  6 43  7 12  0  3
```